# Change timezone in SimpleDateFormat()

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I have problem to convert server timezone to my timezone. My server is in US.

this is my code:

```
long orderID = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh':'mm':'ss' 'a");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));
Date orderTime = new Date(orderID);

System.out.print(sdf.format(orderTime));
```

But it still print US time. How to solve this?

Comment: Please show some examples of output with real data that demonstrates the problem.  You don't have time-of-day in the format, so many times will appear the same in both timezones.

Comment: Why do you have to use a `SimpleDateFormat`? You already have the time in milliseconds, surely there must be some other more appropriate class. Calendar, Date, or something with JodaTime.

Comment: @JoshM how would you represent the `Date` using a `String` and the classes in JDK prior to Java 8 only?

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry for that. I just update my question

Comment: Try GMT+8 instead of Asia/Kuala_lumpur

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, add in `HH:mm.ss` to see the time difference to be sure (ps - You -2 hours behind me)

Comment: I hope you have the same snippet as one you have pasted here. I would double check by printing the timezone to see if it really has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use a decent date-time library instead. That means either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the java.time package bundled in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

In [Joda-Tim](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)e 2.3, some example code.

Instantiate a date-time value, and assign a time zone. Unlike a java.util.Date, a Joda-Time DateTime instance knows its own assigned time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" );
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

Generate a string representation of the date-time value. Use a format that displays only the time, without the date, in a localized format using the JVM's default Locale. If you want a specific non-localized format, use `DateTimeFormat.forPattern` to specify a custom format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "-S" );
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

If you want to specify a Locale, call `formatter.withLocale( yourLocaleInstanceGoesHere)`.

Convert to other time zones.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withTimeZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Convert to a java.util.Date if needed for other classes.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..this give me more knowlegde:)

Comment: FYI there's a bug in this code with the most recent version of Joda-time, it's not `dateTime.withTimeZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)`, it's now just `dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)`